# Inserting data into SQL Server in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to add data into a SQL Server database, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into prod (poductID, Name, Type, Kg/Units, Length, Width Hight, Area/m2) values('" & id.Text & "','" & pdt.Text & "','" & type.Text & "','" & kg.Text & "','" & lg.Text & "','" & wdt.Text & "', '" & ht.Text & "', '" & area.Text & "' )"

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting data into database...." & ex.Message, "insert data")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button13_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click

    id.Clear()
    type.Clear()
    eid.Clear()
    kg.Clear()
    lg.Clear()
    wdt.Clear()
    ht.Clear()
    area.Clear()
End Sub
```

and this below is connection code to the database and it is working:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=JUMAH;Initial Catalog=production;Integrated Security=False;User ID=jumah;Password=256jumah;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False ")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
```

Comment: Hi and welsome to SO. We are keen to help here, but can you please edit your question and format your code? It's highly unreadable now. Also, can you please provide some more information? "it doesn't work" is not enough. What happens? Do you get some error? If so, what is it? What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: That is not the correct way to build SQL - you open the door for all sorts of errors and major problems gluing strings and values together.  Research SQL Parameters.  Also take the time to format your post so the code looks like code and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Are you getting any error? If it is then what error message you are getting? please provide.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is rename fields in your table e.g. remove / and spaces. Make sure field names are not reserved words in SQL-Server.

Tip, when naming fields, e.g. Kg Units can be change to Kg_Units then when needed to display in a control such as a DataGridView assign Kg_Units as the data source for a column then set the column header to Kg/Units.

Make sure the primary key is auto-increment.

**Listen to the comments prior to this reply!!!**

I suggest using a class for data operations, data operations should not be in your form but callable from a data class.

The following is (one of many paths) a blue print to add a new record. Don't simply copy this code but instead revamp the database table as mentioned above first.

SQL Statements are done in XML literal format which means zero string concatenation so we can have a clear picture of the statement.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DataOperations
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Pass in values (you may need to adjust the types for
    ''' the INSERT, last parameter is by ref, create a integer
    ''' variable in the calling method, pass it in here. If
    ''' the operation is successful the integer will have the
    ''' new primary key.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="pName"></param>
    ''' <param name="pType"></param>
    ''' <param name="pUnits"></param>
    ''' <param name="pLength"></param>
    ''' <param name="pWidthHeight"></param>
    ''' <param name="pArea"></param>
    ''' <param name="pNewIdentifier"></param>
    ''' <returns></returns>
    Public Function AddRecord(
        ByVal pName As String,
        ByVal pType As String,
        ByVal pUnits As Integer,
        ByVal pLength As Integer,
        ByVal pWidthHeight As String,
        ByVal pArea As Integer,
        pNewIdentifier As Integer) As Boolean

        Using cn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "TODO"}
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                        INSERT INTO [prod] 
                        (
                            [Name], 
                            [Type], 
                            [Kg/Units], 
                            [Length], 
                            [Width Hight], 
                            [Area/m2]
                        ) 
                        VALUES 
                        (
                            @Name, 
                            @Type, 
                            @Units, 
                            @Length, 
                            @WidthHeight, 
                            @Area
                        ); 
                        SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);
                    </SQL>.Value

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", pName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", pType)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Units", pUnits)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Length", pLength)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WidthHeight", pWidthHeight)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", pArea)

                cn.Open()

                Try
                    pNewIdentifier = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)

                    Return True

                Catch ex As Exception

                    Return False

                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code. And please make sure your connection string properly. I have put the connection string, table and column name for testing purpose.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim query As String = String.Empty
        query &= "INSERT INTO TestType (TestTypeName, Description, Amount) "
        query &= "VALUES (@TestTypeName,@Description, @Amount)"

        Using conn As New SqlConnection("data source=DESKTOP-M8O33JL\SQLEXPRESS2014;initial catalog=MediAid;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=sa12345")
            Using comm As New SqlCommand()
                With comm
                    .Connection = conn
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    .CommandText = query
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TestTypeName", "Test Name")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "Test Description")
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount",300)
                End With
                Try
                    conn.Open()
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch ex As SqlException
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

If you have face further problem. feel free to write in comment section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best practice but you might want to try this.
You might also want to read more about Interface dispose and SQL Syntax in VB.net.

Form:

```
    Private Sub Button12_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("your insert query string")
        Dim dbclass As New DatabaseClass
        If dbclass.fncInsert(cmd) Then
            msgbox("successfull")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
```

DB class:

```
    Public Function fncInsert(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Boolean
    fncInsert = Nothing
    Try
        Using m_sqlCon As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
            Using adpr As New SqlDataAdapter
                cmd.Connection = m_sqlCon
                adpr.InsertCommand = cmd
                fncInsert = If(adpr.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0, True, False)
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        msgbox(ex)
    End Try
End Function
```

sorry for my bad english.